# Unexpected fail when running C++ code with Sublime Text 2 on Windows8

Tags: c++, gcc, sublimetext2, windows-8.1

I just begin to use sublime text 2 on my laptop. I want to compile and run C++ code using sublime text 2.

1. I installed MinGW and g++, and changed the path environment to include the path where MinGW was installed.
2. I opened sublime text 2 and wrote a simple C++ program, named test.c, to do the test.

   #include "stdio.h"

   # test.c

   int main()

   {
       printf("hello");
   }

I did Ctrl+B to compile and got the message:

```
[Finished in 0.8s].
```

3. I used Ctrl+Shift+B to run it and got the following message.

   [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
   [cmd:  [u'bash', u'-c', u"g++ 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.c' -o     'C:\Users\me\Desktop/test' && 'C:\Users\me\Desktop/test'"]]
   [dir:  C:\Users\me\Desktop]
   [path: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\MinGW\bin;]
   [Finished]
4. I tried to solve this problem and did the following things.

   i. Sublime Text 2 --> Tools --> Build System --> New Build System

   ii. in the newly opened window in sublime, I input the following commands.

   {

   ```
   "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
   "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
   "working_dir": "${file_path}",
   "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

   "variants":
   [
   {
       "name": "Run",
       "cmd" : ["${file_path}/${file_base_name}"]
   }
   ]
   ```

   }

   iii. I saved the file as gcc.sublime-build and went back to run test.c. 
   However, the test.exe was not run appropriately and Win8 showed this window, which says

   test.exe has stopped working

   A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. 
   Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

I got this message from sublime text after closing the window:

```
[Finished in 7.6s with exit code 255].
```

I don't why and how to fix it.

Comment: Does test.exe run OK if you start it from Explorer?

Comment: Double click to run test.exe can show "hello" in a cmd window, but in the meanwhile the window appears, saying "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Comment: Your error message in (4) seems to be indicating that Sublime can't find a `bash` shell to execute. Have you installed something that provides a Bourne shell to your system (Cygwin or MingW or git-bash or ....)?

Comment: Oh, I have installed mingw32-gcc-g++, but I may not have bash shell on my labtop. So should I install msys-bash (from mingw-get), too ?

Comment: @WangZiping - if test.exe shows the "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly..." when started from Explorer, then it's the same behavior as when it is started from Sublime, so this is expected behavior.  Why don't you fix test.exe to not have the problem at all?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply install [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)? It includes both compiler and code editor, so you don't need to waste your time on setting up buggy software like Sublime.

Comment: You can also try Code::Blocks , it is a good solution if your're searching for a small and powerful  IDE.